# Virtual Inheritance : Base Ctor not calling in Most Derived Class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

```
class Base
{
      public:
          Base(){}
          Base(int k):a(k) 
          {     
          }
            int a;
};

class X:virtual public Base
{
      public:
            X():Base(10){}
            int x;
};

class Y:virtual public Base
{
      public:
            Y():Base(10){}
            int y;
};

class Z:public X,public Y
{
public:
    Z():X(10){}
};

int main()
{
           Z a;
           cout << a.a;
           return 1;
}
```

In the above case, for `Z():X(10){}` `Base(int k):a(k)` is not calling, but when i change to `Z():Base(10){}` the `Base(int k):a(k)` is called. Why ?

Thank you.

Comment: How can you call `X(10)` when `X` only has a default constructor?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126522

Comment: I think you missed constructor X( int ) to make Z():X(10){} possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you used the `virtual` keyword - that's exactly what it does.

You have to explicitly initialize `Base` in the initializer list of `Z` in order to disambiguate between the initialization in `X` and the initalization in `Y`.

Comment: @Joe, Clean Answer :). Thanks a Lot

Answer (score 3):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193138/virtual-base-class-data-members). The gist is, that when using virtual inheritance you have to call the base class constructor explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

The initializer list in the most derived constructor is used to initialize your base classes. Since class Z inherits from class X and Y which inherits from a common base class, the virtual keyword is used to create only a single subobject for the base class in order to disambiguate when accessing the data member a.