# Using CRTP with virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, crtp, virtual-inheritance

I have a hierarchy of nodes, where "diamond" can occurred.

Every node must be clonable but I don't want to write clone method to every node. So I use CRTP.

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node(){}
    Node(Fill*) { }

    virtual ~Node() {}
    virtual Node * clone() const = 0;

    virtual void id() { std::cout << "Node\n"; }
};

//====================================================================

template <typename Base, typename Derived>
class NodeWrap : public Base
{
public:

    NodeWrap() { } 
    NodeWrap(Fill * arg1) : Base(arg1) { }

    virtual Node *clone() const
    {
        return new Derived(static_cast<Derived const &>(*this));
    }
};
```

works as follows:

```
class NodeA : public NodeWrap<Node, NodeA>
{
public:
    typedef NodeWrap<Node, NodeA> BaseClass;

    NodeA() { }
    NodeA(Fill * f) : BaseClass(f) { }

    virtual void id() { std::cout << "NodeA\n"; }

};
```

**First question:**

There is know [BUG](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/590625/visual-c-incorrectly-reports-ambiguity-when-covariance-is-used-with-virtual-inheritance) in VS when "covariance is used with virtual inheritance".
Is there a way to overcome the bug, and still have covariant types is `clone` method?

I changed return type to be `Node` instead of `Base`. I can live with that, but I would like to have `Base` as return type

**Second question:**
Problem occurred when multiple inheritance comes to play. I created new wrapper, which inherits `virtually`

```
template <typename Base, typename Derived>
class NodeWrapVirtual : public virtual Base
{
public:

    NodeWrapVirtual() { }
    NodeWrapVirtual(Fill * arg1) : Base(arg1) { }

    virtual Node *clone() const
    {
        return new Derived(static_cast<Derived const &>(*this));
    }
};
```

and now building diamond structure:

```
class NodeB : public NodeWrapVirtual<Node, NodeB>
{
public:
typedef NodeWrapVirtual<Node, NodeB> BaseClass;

NodeB() { }
NodeB(Fill * f) : BaseClass(f) { }

virtual void id() { std::cout << "NodeB\n"; }
};

//====================================================================

class NodeC : public NodeWrapVirtual<Node, NodeC>
{
public:
    typedef NodeWrapVirtual<Node, NodeC> BaseClass;

    using BaseClass::clone;

    NodeC() { }
    NodeC(Fill * f) : BaseClass(f) { }

    virtual void id() { std::cout << "NodeC\n"; }
};
```

and problematic diamond node:

```
class NodeD : public NodeWrap<NodeB, NodeD>,
              public NodeWrap<NodeC, NodeD>
{
public:

    typedef NodeWrap<NodeB, NodeD>  BaseClassB;
    typedef NodeWrap<NodeC, NodeD>  BaseClassC;

    NodeD() { }
    NodeD(Fill * f) : BaseClassB(f), BaseClassC(f) { }

    using BaseClassB::clone;  // (1)
    virtual NodeD *clone() const { return new NodeD(*this); }       // (2)

    virtual void id() { std::cout << "NodeD\n"; }
};
```

where are 2 lines I am curious about. (line (1) and (2))

If both lines are removed, there is oblivious compile error, because there is ambiguous `clone` method (from every parent). Since I don't use covariant return types, there should work `clone` method form each parent, so i use line (1) but it doesn't work. Still ambiguous.

So I use line (2) and it works.

Is there a nice way, to avoid writing line (2)?

[HERE](https://ideone.com/O2XrWl) is full working example on ideone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should be very carefull to use virtual inheritance with members inside the virtual base (look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1193516/1918154, "Effective C++", item 20: "Avoid data members in public interfaces" and http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html#faq-25.8). Your `node` gets an pointer to a `fill` which is not used, but it looks like you need it somewhere.

Your problem can be solved when you move the inhertance relationship (`public virtual` and `public`) in the base class for your `NodeWrap`.

```
template <typename Base>
class  InheritVirtual
    : public virtual Base
{};

template <typename... Bases>
class InheritBases
    : public Bases...
{
    virtual Node* clone() const = 0;
    virtual void id() const = 0;
};

class NodeB : public NodeWrap<InheritVirtual<Node>, NodeB>
{ 
   //...
};


class NodeC : public NodeWrap<InheritVirtual<Node>, NodeB>
{ 
   //...
};

class NodeD : public NodeWrap<InheritBases<NodeB,NodeC>, NodeD>
{ 
   //...
};
```

Running [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/89ebc030c758f463).

The pure virtual methods in `InheritBases` are needed because the so called domination rule ([Dominance in virtual inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210860/dominance-in-virtual-inheritance)).

The problem to be solved is a way to transfer paramters to the right constructor in case of multiple bases. Unlike `Node` (wich is a virtual base) it is ok to let `NodeB` and `NodeC` have member variables and non trivial constructors.

Answer (score 3):

Each virtual function must have a unique final overrider in each derived class. This has nothing to do with name lookup (the requirement is for the functions, not for their names), thus `using` is irrelevant.

Use a multi-base-classed node class template:

```
 template <class Derived, class Base1, class Base2>
 class node2 : //  etc
 // or use a variadic template if you have more than two bases
```

As for covariant returns, they are strictly unnecessary, if convenient. You can always split each virtual function into a private virtual and a public non-virtual.  This comes handy if you want to return covariant smart pointers, which is not supported by the regular covariant return machinery at all.

Comment: A bit more detail on covariant returns: any time you want to call `clone()`, *either* you already know the most-derived concrete type of the instance you want to call it on, in which case you don't need a virtual method; *or* you don't know it, in which case your code couldn't make use of any return type more specific than `Base*` anyway.